# Background changed slider bullet view of input type range

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, range

How come is this possible!? In firefox, Change in background, changes the look of the `input` type `range` bullet slider. 
The HTML markup

```
<input type="range" id="slide"/>
```

The CSS code

```css
input[type='range'] {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    background:#DBEAF9;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some links for your reference of styling input type range in Chrome and Firefox

https://coderwall.com/p/rw6i0q

http://codepen.io/Topcoat/pen/BskEn

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:Jonathan_Watt/range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User%3aJonathan_Watt/range)